# reading Excel file Date/time Incorrectly

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with a column as time and a separate column as date. I'm using the code below to read it :

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'df.xlsx', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']])
```

This works perfectly when the date is the same; however, if the dates change then it read it falsely. For example, the excel file is as below:

[image]

If I read it using this code the results will be like this:

```
2021-04-03 00:00:00 23:52:11,A
2021-04-03 00:00:00 23:56:05,A
2021-04-03 00:00:00 23:59:27,A
2021-04-04 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:03:33,B
2021-04-04 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:04:33,B
2021-04-04 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:06:43,B
2021-04-04 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:10:17,B
```

How can I fix this so the dataframe has separate columns with the correct date and time like below?

```
2021-04-03  23:52:11,A
2021-04-03  23:56:05,A
2021-04-03  23:59:27,A
2021-04-04  00:03:33,B
2021-04-04  00:04:33,B
2021-04-04  00:06:43,B
2021-04-04  00:10:17,B
```

Excel file : https://www.apispreadsheets.com/table/lEooNma9w3X2XfaL/

Comment: Could you share sample excel file?

Comment: The sample is in the question

Comment: That's not a reproducible excel file. This is just text.

Comment: I added the excel file. https://www.apispreadsheets.com/table/lEooNma9w3X2XfaL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with different date formats within the same data, you can use [dateutil.parser](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c).

Example usage:

```
import dateutil.parser as parser

parser.parse("2021-04-04 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:03:33,B")
```

The output will be a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object, so you can use it to specify the final output format.